# Execute a command on the PATH using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I have the DVCS Mercurial on my PATH in a Windows system respective in a GNU/Linux system. If I open a Bash shell in GNU/Linux I can execute hg (the Mercurial command), the same goes if I open a Command Prompt in Windows.

I would like to execute hg and check exit status and capture the output. I know about the subprocess module and check_output. But I can´t get it to use my PATH. I would prefer not to hard code the path as I want the script to work as long as you have Mercurial on your path.

An example would be greatly appreciated.

Happy holidays!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already have `hg` in your path you shouldn't need anything special in the call to `subprocess` since you should get the same environment.

Anyway, if you want to explicitly add a PATH environment variable to your subprocess, you can do this:

```
env = os.environ.copy()
env['PATH'] = <whatever you need here>
subprocess.Popen(<hg command>, env=env)
```

This code copies the environment you're getting from your shell and overwrites the `PATH` variable. You might want to append to `PATH` instead if you're going to use the same `env` dictionary to run other commands.

There's no need to copy the whole environment, but this will prevent other problems you might have from happening because other environment variables are missing.